# Get-Content function is not working in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to read XML content from which is stored in a text file. But it is not working properly. Please go through my code as mention below:

```
Write-Host 'Welcome'
$path='D:\SOAP\PozEncoXML.txt'
$xml=[xml](Get-Content -path $path)
Write-Host 'File Content'
write-host $xml
$node= $xml.Envelope.Body.uploadFileToUcm.document.Content='Hello world'
Write-Host $node
```

In line no 3 of the above code I am trying to read XML content from the text file. If I remove [xml] then Get-Content is working fine. But need that content in XML format. Can anyone help me to overcome this issue?

This is the content of my file content

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/financialUtilService/types/" xmlns:fin="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/financialUtilService/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <typ:uploadFileToUcm>
     <typ:document>
        <fin:Content></fin:Content>
        <fin:FileName>xxxxx.csv</fin:FileName>
        <fin:ContentType>csv</fin:ContentType>
        <fin:DocumentTitle>Journal Import</fin:DocumentTitle>
        <fin:DocumentAuthor>xxxx</fin:DocumentAuthor>
        <fin:DocumentSecurityGroup>FAFusionImportExport</fin:DocumentSecurityGroup>
        <fin:DocumentAccount>fin$/generalLedger$/import$</fin:DocumentAccount>
        <fin:DocumentName>?</fin:DocumentName>
        <fin:DocumentId>?</fin:DocumentId>
     </typ:document>
  </typ:uploadFileToUcm>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: "*But it is not working properly*" - what is happening instead? For example, does your code continue to run with unexpected results, or do you see an error message? Note this line is probably incorrect ```$xml.Envelope.Body.uploadFileToUcm.document.Content='Hello world'``` - the second ```=``` is an *assignment* not a *comparison* which might mean the rest of your program doesn't behave how you expect...

Comment: Actually my xml file is containing a SOAP format, using that format I have to send data to UCM. This code is working other server.

Comment: Have 2 variables, one with the source text, and one converted to an xmldocument object.  write-host badly tries to convert the xmldocument object to text.

Comment: Hmm, $xml.innerxml and $xml.outerxml properties seem to have the source text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works here:

```powershell
[xml] $x = gc infile.xml
$x.Envelope.Body.uploadFileToUcm.document.content='Hello World'
$x.save("$((pwd).path)\outfile.xml")
gc outfile.xml
```

Output:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/financialUtilService/types/" xmlns:fin="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/financialUtilService/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <typ:uploadFileToUcm>
      <typ:document>
        <fin:Content>Hello World</fin:Content>
        <fin:FileName>xxxxx.csv</fin:FileName>
        <fin:ContentType>csv</fin:ContentType>
        <fin:DocumentTitle>Journal Import</fin:DocumentTitle>
        <fin:DocumentAuthor>xxxx</fin:DocumentAuthor>
        <fin:DocumentSecurityGroup>FAFusionImportExport</fin:DocumentSecurityGroup>
        <fin:DocumentAccount>fin$/generalLedger$/import$</fin:DocumentAccount>
        <fin:DocumentName>?</fin:DocumentName>
        <fin:DocumentId>?</fin:DocumentId>
      </typ:document>
    </typ:uploadFileToUcm>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Instead of save into a file $x.save("$((pwd).path)\outfile.xml"), can we store it into a variable?

Comment: Just use .ToString() .

Comment: @ShivShankarMaiti: so you want the xml text? Perhaps `$x.outerxml` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

assuming the file is well formatted as xml, I would create a new instance of a xml object and use the load method:

```
$path='D:\SOAP\PozEncoXML.txt'
$xml = New-Object -TypeName xml
$xml.Load($path)
[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($Xml.OuterXml).ToString()
```

Output

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/financialUtilService/types/" xmlns:fin="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/financialUtilService/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <typ:uploadFileToUcm>
      <typ:document>
        <fin:Content>Hello world</fin:Content>
        <fin:FileName>xxxxx.csv</fin:FileName>
        <fin:ContentType>csv</fin:ContentType>
        <fin:DocumentTitle>Journal Import</fin:DocumentTitle>
        <fin:DocumentAuthor>xxxx</fin:DocumentAuthor>
        <fin:DocumentSecurityGroup>FAFusionImportExport</fin:DocumentSecurityGroup>
        <fin:DocumentAccount>fin$/generalLedger$/import$</fin:DocumentAccount>
        <fin:DocumentName>?</fin:DocumentName>
        <fin:DocumentId>?</fin:DocumentId>
      </typ:document>
    </typ:uploadFileToUcm>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But this code is returning only #document when I am displaying the content using Write-host $xml.

Comment: try ```write-host $xml.OuterXml```

Comment: @Shiv Shankar Maiti - sorry did not recognize that the only issue you have is to display it on the screen, I updated the code.

Comment: @Toni thanks for your response. My problem is not with display. My file containing SOAP format (xml). I have to add my data to that Content node where we have mentioned 'Hello World' and send the entire xml to SOAP API.

Comment: @Shiv Shankar Maiti  - ok Thor already showed you one way how to change a value and save it to the xml... this works for you or?

Comment: @Toni it is working but I want to store in a variable instead of save to a file.

Comment: just do not execute the save operation, the variable has been updated already